# Vaadin: Exclude readonly fields from tabbing order

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

In a Vaadin 23 form there are some input fields. Some of them are read-only.

I want to exclude these read-only fields from tabbing order.

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/input-fields#focus states hits:

> Read-only elements cannot be edited, but they are in the tabbing order and can thus receive focus.

Is there a way to exclude read-only elements from tabbing order, but keep all other properties as-is? E.g. I'd like to keep the functionality for the user to mark the content and copy it.

Disabling the input fields (instead of setting them readonly) is not intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting tabindex="-1" for those fields should be enough.

```java
field.setTabIndex(-1);
```

https://vaadin.com/api/platform/23.1.1/com/vaadin/flow/component/Focusable.html#setTabIndex(int)